# Using simple SOAP in .NET Compact Framework

Tags: soap, .net-3.5, compact-framework

In one of my windows CE programs I have to check a connection with a server. Since we interact with that server using SOAP I wanted to call a simple SOAP function on that server (something like getDateTime) to make sure that the connection is OK.
Is there a simple way to do that using .NET 3.5 CF?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to leverage the work done on [PocketSOAP](http://www.4s4c.com/pocketsoap/) to do all of the SOAP-related heavy lifting.  There are [C# samples on the site too](http://www.4s4c.com/samples/psdotnetinterop2.aspx).